# gulp-jshint specify files which should go through jshint() and ignore other files

Tags: javascript, build-process, gulp, jshint

I have situation where i'm building minified script through gulp, from scripts that are either vendor scripts or my scripts, something like:

```
var paths = {
    public      : './public/javascripts',
    api         : './public/API',
    vendor      : './public/vendor',
    destination : './dist'
};

gulp.task('scripts-out', function() {
    gulp.src([
        paths.public + '/a.js',
        paths.public + '/b.js',
        paths.public + '/c.js',
        paths.public + '/d.js',
        paths.api    + '/e.js',
        paths.public + '/f.js'
    ])
    .pipe(jshint())
    .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'))
    .pipe(concat('out.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.destination + '/javascripts'));
});
```

Only `e.js` is not vendor script and only that script should go through jshint(), from official documentation of the plugin i can't see solution for this.

I tried passing `config` object to jshint(), something like:

```
pipe(jshint({
    files: paths.api     + '/e.js'
}))
```

That was just speculation which don't work. Side question of this how to force jshint to write results to some file instead of console?

**EDIT: FIND SOLUTION**
I find the way through the `.jshintignore` file, which should be in the root of the project, for example if you want to ignore all from the vendor folder you can just add one line to `.jshintignore` file: `public/src/vendor/*`

Comment: `.jshintignore` approach worked. Please provide it as answer & mark it as accepted one !

Answer (score 3):

You could use [gulp-filter](https://npmjs.org/package/gulp-filter) to filter which files get passed to `jshint`:

```
var gulpFilter = require('gulp-filter');
var filter = gulpFilter([paths.public + '/e.js']);

gulp.task('scripts-out', function() {
    return gulp.src([
        paths.public + '/a.js',
        paths.public + '/b.js',
        paths.public + '/c.js',
        paths.public + '/d.js',
        paths.api    + '/e.js',
        paths.public + '/f.js'
    ])
    .pipe(filter)
    .pipe(jshint())
    .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'))
    .pipe(filter.restore())
    .pipe(concat('out.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.destination + '/javascripts'));
});
```

---

New version(3.0.1) has interface updates:

```
 // you should pass {restore: true} for restore ability
 var filter = gulpFilter([paths.public + '/e.js'], {restore: true});
 ...
 // filter.restore is now object, not a method
 .pipe(filter.restore)
```

Comment: i actually find the way through creating .jshintignore file in the root of the project with content public/vendor/*